# Is there a way to checkout file from another branch on specific commitID?

Tags: git

I tried the following:

```
git checkout master 75d533d -- PagedList.js
fatal: only one reference expected, 2 given.
git checkout master -- PagedList.js 75d533d
error: pathspec '75d533d' did not match any file(s) known to git.
git checkout origin/master 75d533d -- PagedList.js
fatal: only one reference expected, 2 given.
```

Anyway, my goal is to checkout PagedList.js from master branch with the version 75d533d

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A branch is just a pointer to a commit. Behind the nice command line, for many operations the branch is the synonym for the commit it points to.

> Anyway, my goal is to checkout PagedList.js from master branch with the version 75d533d.

The `master` branch, as any branch, can move from one commit to another, from one branch of the history to another. The *"master branch with the version 75d533d"* might not be always correct. But this is a different story.

What you want is the checkout the file `PagedList.js` as it was on commit `75d533d` (no matter if that commit belongs to the current history of `master` or not). The `master` branch is not involved here.

If I made my point clear you probably already understood where is your error. Drop any reference to `master` from your command and you're good to go:

```
git checkout 75d533d -- PagedList.js
```

Read more about [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) or type `git help checkout` on your command prompt.

Comment: thank you. I did not know commitIDs are unique to branches

Answer (score 2):

As already said:

> git checkout 75d533d -- PagedList.js

also this works:

> git checkout 75d533d PagedList.js

ensure the "PagedList.js" has the correct file path or you'll get a

> error: pathspec 'PagedList.js' did not match any file(s) known to git

Answer (score 0):

Try simply `git checkout 75d533d -- PagedList.js`.

This should be reference "enough".